# How to make the Accordion tab's title responsive?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

The title can sometimes be a long string but I need to show it whole.

```
<p:accordionPanel cache="false" value="#{tasksBean.getTasks()}"
                  var="task" activeIndex="null">
    <p:tab>
        <f:facet name="title">
             <h:outputText  value="loremIpsumloremIpsumlorem
                                   IpsumloremIpsumloremIpsum
                                   loremIpsumloremIpsumlorem
                                   IpsumloremIpsumloremIpsuml"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with

```
.ui-accordion-header.ui-helper-reset.ui-state-default {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```